# Is it possible to use EF Function Translation during an Add in Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, translation

Long story short, we have spent the past few days creating a translation to add decrypt/encrypt by key into Entity Framework.

The following select works (the hardcoded key "test" is just for a testing environment, this will be stored with keystores later)
The EF.Functions.Decrypt triggers a translation expression that writes custom SQL for Entity Framework to utilize the internal decryption methods.

```
var filteredSet = Set.Include(x => x.Table2)
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Where(x => x.Table2.IsSomething)
            .Select(m => new Model
        {
            Id = m.Id,
            Decrypted = EF.Functions.Decrypt("test", m.Encrypted), //string
            Table2 = m.Table2,
            Encrypted = m.Encrypted //byte[]
        }).ToList();
```

The following (as I sort of expected going into it) does not.

```
public Model createNew(string Data)
    {
        Set.Add(
                new Model
                {
                    Encrypted = EF.Functions.Encrypt("test", Data)
                }
            );
        return new Model();
    }
```

When used in this manner it attempts to create a new model object using the EF Function and throws an InvalidOperationError.
Is there a way to perform an Add in EF where it translates this function rather attempting the execute the code into a model?

Comment: It is not possible via EF Core's Change Tracker. Only via third party extensions.

Comment: Do you know of any extensions exactly? or any documentation on how they accomplish it?

Comment: The problem is that there's no expression involved in creating/updating/deleting entities, while `EF.Functions` is nothing but a placeholder for function calls that are *only* meaningful in expressions. Outside expressions they have no implementation. And as Svyaloslav indicated, EF's change tracker can't handle it, it can only deal with set values. That said, I like the out-of-the-box thinking here. I think EF *could* provide an API for injecting functions into CUD queries, but the question is if they'll see enough added value in such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since currently there is no solution to pass Expression Tree to EF Core ChangeTracker, you can try [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

Encryption extension methods:

```cs
public static class SqlFunctions
{
    [Sql.Function("DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE", ServerSideOnly = true)]
    public static string DecryptByPassPhrase(string passphrase, byte[]? ciphertext) 
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    [Sql.Function("ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE", ServerSideOnly = true)]
    public static byte[]? EncryptByPassPhrase(string passphrase, string? cleartext) 
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

}
```

And basic CRUD operations:

**Select**

```cs
var filteredSet = Set
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .Where(x => x.Table2.IsSomething)
    .Select(m => new Model
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Decrypted = SqlFunctions.DecryptByPassPhrase("test", m.Encrypted), //string
        Table2 = m.Table2,
        Encrypted = m.Encrypted //byte[]
    })
    .ToLinqToDB()
    .ToList();
```

**Insert**

```cs
Set.ToLinqToDBTable()
    .Insert(() => new Model
    {
        Encrypted = SqlFunctions.EncryptByPassPhrase("test", Data)
    })
```

**Update**

```cs
Set
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .Set(x => s.Encrypted, x => SqlFunctions.EncryptByPassPhrase("test", Data))
    .Update();
```