# How can I encrypt column with EF Core & SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, encryption

I have an application using SQL Server and .NET 5, EF Core 5. I need to encrypt some sensitive columns in the database.

I tried methods like Always Encrypted with Secure Enclaves and Symmetric Key encryption.

I couldn't use Always Encrypted due to limitations. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves?view=sql-server-ver15#confidential-queries

Then I tried to use Symmetric Key on a demo project:

```
[Table("TestTableColumnEncrypt")]
public class TestTableColumnEncrypt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NumberCol { get; set; }
    public string StrCol { get; set; }
    public decimal DecimalCol { get; set; }
    public int EncryptedNumberCol { get; set; }
    public string EncryptedStrCol { get; set; }
    public decimal EncryptedDecimalCol { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestTableColumnEncrypt>().Property(x => x.EncryptedNumberCol)
        .HasConversion(x => this.Encrypt(x), y => Convert.ToInt32(this.Decrypt(y)));
    ...
}

public byte[] Encrypt(object value)
{
    var encryptedValue = this.Set<FakeEncryptModel>().FromSqlRaw("sp_OpenKeyAndEncryptColumnValue {0}", value.ToString()).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().EncryptedValue;
    
    return (byte[])encryptedValue;
}

public object Decrypt(byte[] encryptedValue)
{
    var decryptedValue = this.Set<FakeDecryptModel>().FromSqlRaw("sp_DecryptColumnValue {0}", encryptedValue).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().DecryptedValue;

    return decryptedValue;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestContext ctx = new TestContext();
        
    if (!ctx.TestTableColumnEncrypts.Any())
    {
        var data = new List<TestTableColumnEncrypt>();

        foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 5))
        {
            data.Add(new TestTableColumnEncrypt
                {
                    NumberCol = 1 + item,
                    StrCol = "str" + item,
                    DecimalCol = 1M + item,
                    EncryptedNumberCol = 1 + item,
                    EncryptedStrCol = "str" + item,
                    EncryptedDecimalCol = 1M + item
                });
           ctx.Add(data[item - 1]);
       }

       ctx.SaveChanges();
   }
   else
   {
       // var data1 = ctx.TestTableColumnEncrypts.FromSqlRaw("Select * from dbo.TestTableColumnEncrypt").ToList(); //OK
       // var data2 = ctx.TestTableColumnEncrypts.ToList(); //OK
            
       var data3 = ctx.TestTableColumnEncrypts.Where(x => x.EncryptedNumberCol = 2).FirstOrDefault(); //NOT OK
        var data4 = ctx.TestTableColumnEncrypts.Where(x => x.EncryptedNumberCol > 2).FirstOrDefault(); //NOT OK
    }
}
```

I use `EncryptByKey` and `DecryptByKey` functions for encryption and decryption.

Inserting the data is successful. It also succeeds when I try to get all the data of the table.

But when I use `where` conditions with LINQ queries, EF Core encrypts the condition value(2) on conversion process. And the result queries are like:

> Equality operation failed. EncryptByKey function is non-deterministic, so it generates always different value for the same plaintext.
>
> SELECT TOP(1) [t].[Id], [t].[DecimalCol], [t].[EncryptedDecimalCol], [t].[EncryptedNumberCol], [t].[EncryptedStrCol], [t].[NumberCol], [t].[StrCol]
> FROM [TestTableColumnEncrypt] AS [t]
> WHERE [t].[EncryptedNumberCol] = 0x00ACD3D67A73667D4E640251A675D7D60200000022FDE885432CFE38FFBBBE6EC16E276D27817A2B0F73AB863D916F8A1CC2EFB5
>
> SELECT TOP(1) [t].[Id], [t].[DecimalCol], [t].[EncryptedDecimalCol], [t].[EncryptedNumberCol], [t].[EncryptedStrCol], [t].[NumberCol], [t].[StrCol]
> FROM [TestTableColumnEncrypt] AS [t]
> WHERE [t].[EncryptedNumberCol] > 0x00ACD3D67A73667D4E640251A675D7D6020000008B26CC41884F22FB10231E2BC88AA7B439BC91EF5E71AD8DCA04EFF0C2AF2167

Here is the problem, when I use the Comparison operator with LINQ query, SQL compares the data between two encrypted value, in an other words, it compares the data between two `VARBINARY(MAX)` value. Therefore, the comparison operation fails.

How can I use comparison operator on encrypted columns in LINQ queries?

Do you have any suggestion for an encryption method that can retrieve data with raw SQL and LINQ queries?

Comment: First make sure you are not using any encoding which may change the data.  Second you have a very long number which is 52 bytes.  Should your data be a bytes array instead of a 52 (8 * 52 = 416 bits) byte number (2^416)

Comment: You cannot use properties with conversion in LINQ queries. It is known limitation. Anyway maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68113257/10646316) may help.

Comment: I think the error is saying EF doesn't know how to compare types of  VARBINARY(max), but perhaps if they were both converted to a string it may work.